# Using the same 5060 port on Asterisk, DNS server running VM

Tags: virtual-machine, sip, asterisk, openser

I have SIP servers at home running OpenSER 1.1.1 and Asterisk 1.4.01/ DNS server (two computer) but I wondered if it is possible to run one single computer running 2 VMs (Debian and Debian) to run OpenSer and Asterisk/DNS server, respectively.

Currently the port 5060 is used to communicate between the two computers (needless to say each computer has a static IP address), but what I would like to do is to have a single computer running two VMs running OpenSer and Asterisk/DNS server. Is it possible to have them talking each other via the same port 5060 ? Does it create a conflict ?

Please let me know.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If each VM has it's own IP address, it will work.

Comment: Ok but then how do I set a static IP address to each VM ? Since a static IP address is only assigned if there's a MAC address.

Comment: In addition, I have these SIP servers running 192.168.1.xxx and would like to have all of them running under one machine with VM each having a static IP address of 192.168.1.xxx

Comment: A VM is usualy assigned a MAC address by the virtualization software. Also, if you want a static IP, you have to set it yourself. Each having a static IP is not a problem. I suggest searching on Goole for "static IP address" and how to configure IP addresses on your virtualization software.

Comment: I just attempted the following : Computer A and B are connected in the same network and can ping each other. A has VM1 and VM2 and A can ping VM1 and VM2 or vice versa, but B can not ping VM1 or VM2. I need to ping VM1 and VM2 from B. Please help !

Comment: Too hard to explain in a comment. Please ask this question in http://serverfault.com/. Put all the details (OS of host and VMs, virtualization software used, etc.).